# Resources to learn ActiveResource in Rails 3 - in pragmatic way

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

Can somebody point me to resources that will help me understand A to Z of ActiveResource in Rails 3?

I tried looking out for books and articles in vain :(

Pointers to any open-sourced project that I can play with should also be of help.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having recently worked with ActiveResource I can empathize with you. I can tell you that there hasn't been much work done on ActiveResource since Rails 2.3. I've heard rumor that there's a rewrite coming after 3.1 (or maybe it's actually been done in 3.1).

I'd suggest the Railscasts at [ActiveResource Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics) and [More On ActiveResource](http://railscasts.com/episodes/95-more-on-activeresource) If you have a copy of The Rails 3 Way there is a chapter there. Otherwise, the best resource I was able to find was the code itself.

Comment: Thanks, I had watched the screencasts that you mentioned but couldn't really get the complete picture. I'm sure there is more in reality and that is what I'm looking out for. It is with this intention that I had posted this question.

Comment: They actually added support for all ActiveRecord types in ARes 3.1.

Comment: Oooh Oooh Oooh! Gotta check that out! Thanks!